Find a graph which is strictly balanced but not strongly balanced.
A graph G is called strictly balanced if all proper subgraphs H of G satisfies
$$\frac{|E(H)|}{|V(H)|}\ < \frac{|E(G)|}{|V(G)|}$$
A graph G is called strongly balanced if every subgraph H of G satisfies
$$\frac{|E(H)|}{|V(H)|-1}\ \leq \frac{|E(G)|}{|V(G)|-1}$$
Easy to see that strongly balanced implies strictly balanced.
My guess is that other direction is not true, but haven't been able to produce such an example.

Suppose $G$ consists of two cycles - one of length $3$, and one of length $4$ - meeting at a vertex. Then $|E(G)|= 7$ and $|V(G)|=6$.
If $H$ is a proper subgraph of $G$, it has at most one cycle, so $\frac{|E(H)|}{|V(H)|} \le 1 < \frac{|E(G)|}{|V(G)|}$. Therefore $G$ is strictly balanced.
On the other hand, $\frac{|E(G)|}{|V(G)|-1} = \frac75$, and if we let $H$ be the $3$-cycle subgraph, then $\frac{|E(H)|}{|V(H)|-1} = \frac32$. Since $\frac32 > \frac75$, $G$ is not strongly balanced.
